# Convert javascript regex to asp.net vb

Tags: javascript, .net, regex

I'm using the following regex to validate an email address text box in javascript:-

```
var regex = /^[\_]*([a-z0-9]+(\.|\_*)?)+@([a-z][a-z0-9\-]+(\.|\-*\.))+[a-z]{2,6}$/i;
```

I need to also run it in the back end of the asp.NET(4) VB site to prevent injection.

When I convert it to what I think it should be for .NET and run it in http://myregextester.com/ set to use .NET and VB it passes:-

```
^[_]*([a-z0-9]+(.|_*)?)+@([a-z][a-z0-9\-]+(.|-*.))+[a-z]{2,6}$
```

However when I put it in my code it doesn't work:-

```
If (Not Regex.IsMatch(theEmail, "^[_]*([a-z0-9]+(.|_*)?)+@([a-z][a-z0-9\-]+(.|-*.))+[a-z]{2,6}$")) Then                    
    Return False
Else
    Return True
End If
```

Any help with the conversion to VB would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `\-` to `-`

```
^[_]*([a-z0-9]+(.|_*)?)+@([a-z][a-z0-9-]+(.|-*.))+[a-z]{2,6}$
```

And also set `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`. Since `/i` is set.

Here `i` indicates `IgnoreCase`.

Your code will be

```
If (Not Regex.IsMatch(theEmail, "^[_]*([a-z0-9]+(.|_*)?)+@([a-z][a-z0-9-]+(.|-*.))+[a-z]{2,6}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) Then                    
    Return False
Else
    Return True
End If
```

Comment: Unescaping `-` won't make a difference. Adding an ignore case option is good. As it is now, your regex matches `somebody@A-B@@google`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the only difference between the regexes is that the original one uses a literal dot `\.` whereas the second one uses a dot `.` metacharacter. The metacharacter will match anything, the literal dot will just match a dot character.

Try puting the escape back on the dot.

Your two regexes,

old

```
 ^ [\_]* 
 (
      [a-z0-9]+ 
      ( \. | \_* )?
 )+
 @
 (
      [a-z] [a-z0-9\-]+ 
      ( \. | \-*\. )
 )+
 [a-z]{2,6} $
```

new

```
 ^ [_]* 
 (
      [a-z0-9]+ 
      ( . | _* )?
 )+
 @
 (
      [a-z] [a-z0-9\-]+ 
      ( . | -*. )
 )+
 [a-z]{2,6} $
```